# mysql database is missing

Tags: mysql, centos6

I had installed mysql server on centos 6. But whenever I tried to change the root password it is showing access denied. On checking the show database I am not able to see the mysql database. So the mysql database is missing.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) /etc/init.d/mysql stop
>
> 2)vi /root/db.reset.sql UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
>
> 3) mysqld_safe --init-file=/root/db.reset.sql &
>
> 3)/etc/init.d/mysql start
>
> 4) killall mysql    /etc/init.d/mysql start

Hopefully things should be resolved   :-)